# CreateFileA in Windows API in NASM 64 revisited: invalid parameter

Tags: windows, winapi, nasm

I am creating a file in NASM 64 using CreateFileA in the Windows API.  Yesterday I posted a question on this, which brought out some useful comments.  Today I wrote this section in C and compliled it with Pelles C compiler, and got the disassembly from x64dbg so I can use the output in NASM.  I put the disassembly code into my NASM project, and here's the program in NASM as it is now:

```
CreateAuditFile:
sub rsp,38
xor eax,eax
mov qword [rsp+30],rax
mov eax,80
mov dword [rsp+28],eax
mov eax,2
mov dword [rsp+20],eax
xor r9,r9
xor r8d,r8d
mov edx,40000000
mov rcx,FileName_1
;lea rcx,[rel FileName_1]
call CreateFileA
call GetLastError
mov rdi,FileAuditString ; not from the disassembly
mov [rdi],rax ; not from the disassembly
xor eax,eax
add rsp,38
ret
```

That's the disassembly of this C code (done as a console app):

```
int main(void)
{
    char* File_Name ="C:\\Audit_File_P1";
    HANDLE hFile;

    hFile = CreateFileA(
        File_Name, 
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        NULL);
}
```

This works in C, but in NASM it returns an error code 87, "invalid parameter."  I notice two things:  (1) the first line is sub rsp,38, which is an odd number and not 16-byte aligned; (2) for the file name (FileName_1), the disassembly shows 
"lea rcx,qword ptr ds:[140006270]" but in NASM we use "mov rcx,FileName_1" instead of lea where the file name string is defined in the .data section, as it is here (FileName_1: db "c:\AuditFile_1.txt",0).  Also, it inserts a qword parameter at [rsp+30] and a dword at [rsp+28] but a dword needs four bytes, not two, which seems wrong but it works from the C version.

So my question is:  which parameter(s) is/are incorrect?

Thanks very much.

Comment: `[rsp+20h]` must be - **hex** and so on. `sub rsp,38h` - again.. `GetLastError` must not be unconditional, you lost result of `CreateFile`

Comment: @RbMm - Great!  It works now.  Thanks very much for your help yesterday and today.

Comment: `GetLastError` is only relevant **if** the function call before it failed, and if that function is specifically documented to report the failure reason via `GetLastError`. You're calling it without first knowing that `CreateFileA` failed, so the error value may or may not be valid.  **Always** check the return value of any WinAPI function, and do **not** call `GetLastError` without knowing that it's appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved with the help of others above, and I am posting the full correct code below for others who need this information in the future:

```
CreateAuditFile:
mov rcx,FileName_1
sub rsp,56  ; 38h
xor eax,eax
mov qword [rsp+48],rax ; 30h
mov eax,80
mov dword [rsp+40],eax ; 28h
mov eax,2
mov dword [rsp+32],eax ; 20h
xor r9,r9
xor r8d,r8d
mov edx,40000000
call CreateFileA
mov rdi,OutputFileHandle
mov [rdi+r15],rax
xor eax,eax
add rsp,56 ;38h
ret
```

Here is what changed (changes are followed by a comment and ***):

```
CreateAuditFile:
sub rsp,38 - should be sub rsp,56 ***
xor eax,eax
mov qword [rsp+30],rax - should be mov qword [rsp+48],rax ***
mov eax,80
mov dword [rsp+28],eax - should be mov dword [rsp+40],eax ***
mov eax,2
mov dword [rsp+20],eax - should be mov dword [rsp+32],eax ***
xor r9,r9
xor r8d,r8d
mov edx,40000000
mov rcx,FileName_1
call CreateFileA
call GetLastError - do not call this without testing the result of CreateFileA ***
mov rdi,FileAuditString - not needed ***
mov [rdi],rax - not needed ***
mov rdi,OutputFileHandle - use this to capture the file handle ***
mov [rdi+r15],rax - use this to capture the file handle ***
xor eax,eax
add rsp,38 - should be add rsp,56 ***
ret
```

Thanks very much to everyone who responded.

Comment: @Raymond Chen - please see my answer above.  I revised it to show what changed.

Comment: I think the real problem was that you confused hex and decimal. When you wrote `rsp+30` you meant to add hex `0x30` (decimal 48) to `rsp`, but instead you added decimal 30 (hex `0x1e)`. Similarly for the other numbers.

Comment: @Raymond Chen - that's right.  When I got the disassembly the values were hex, but none of the values had an h by them (e.g. 38h), so I wrongly assumed decimal.  Also, the GetLastError must be called only if the call to CreateFileA fails.  Thanks again.